# Вылетает приложение в Android Pie

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть приложение викторина, работает используя БД..На Android 9 вылетает пишет что не найдена таблица. Подскажите пожалуйста как лечится в моем случае? Ниже прикладываю класс DBHelper

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "quiz_db.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Context myContext;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        try {
            DB_PATH = myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).toString();
            createDataBase();
            openDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Cursor getRecords(String category) {
        return database.query(
                DBContract.Entry.TABLE_RECORDS,
                null,
                DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_CATEGORY + " = ?",
                new String[] {category},
                null,
                null,
                null);
    }

    public Cursor getAllRecords() {
        return database.query(
                DBContract.Entry.TABLE_RECORDS,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null);
    }

    public void deleteRecords() {
        database.delete(DBContract.Entry.TABLE_RECORDS, null, null);
    }

    public List<QuestionModel> getAllQuestions(long id) {
        List<QuestionModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
        database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        database.beginTransaction();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(
                DBContract.Entry.TABLE_QUESTIONS
                ,null
                ,DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_CATEGORYID + " = ? "
                ,new String[] {Long.toString(id)}
                ,null
                ,null
                ,null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            QuestionModel question = new QuestionModel();
            question.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Entry._ID)));
            question.setQuestion(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_QUESTION)));
            question.setAnswer(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_ANSWER)));
            question.setOpt1(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_OPT1)));
            question.setOpt2(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_OPT2)));
            question.setOpt3(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_OPT3)));
            question.setOpt4(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_OPT4)));
            list.add(question);
        }

        database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        database.endTransaction();
        cursor.close();
        database.close();
        return list;
    }

    public Cursor getCategories() {
        return database.query(DBContract.Entry.TABLE_CATEGORY, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {

            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // база не существует
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        String outFileName = DB_PATH;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(database != null)
            database.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

> Process: ru.app.quizpumpbrains, PID: 9184 java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   An error occurred while executing doInBackground() at
>   android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:161)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) Caused by:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: category_tab
>   (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM category_tab
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method) at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37) at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1408)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1126)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1294)
>   at
>   ru.app.quizpumpbrains.data.DBHelper.getCategories(DBHelper.java:103)
>   at
>   ru.app.quizpumpbrains.activity.CategoriesActivity$MyCursorLoader.onLoadInBackground(CategoriesActivity.java:128)
>   at
>   ru.app.quizpumpbrains.activity.CategoriesActivity$MyCursorLoader.onLoadInBackground(CategoriesActivity.java:113)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:45)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:138)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)

Comment: `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: category_tab` - это из стектрейса, который вы приложили, то есть проблема в том, что в БД отсутствует таблица `category_tab`

Comment: А если поставить приложение "на чистую" (то есть сначала удалив его с устройства/эмулятора)? И не пишет ли при этом `"Error copying database"` в лог? Просто я не раз видел эту реализацию хелпера и меня удивляет вызов `this.getReadableDatabase();` перед копированием базы - мне кажется, что открытая база таки обязана не дать себя перезаписать.

Comment: Да, самое главное - в этом хелпере нет реализации обновления базы. Если вы изменили её в ассетах, то при обновлении установленного ранее приложения изменения не применяются - база остаётся старая. Наверное поэтому у вас и вылет, что таблицу вы добавили после первой установки.

Comment: даже если на чистую ОС ставить все равно ошибку выдавал. Нашел другую реализацию.. В ответ свой добавлю

Comment: @woesss там есть реализация обновления и она довольно примитивная, она описана в faq к базе данных. просто нужно поднять версию на 1, ну и там по мелочи.

Comment: @Романыч, вы пишете о хелпере из какой-то неизвестной нам библиотеки (которую стоило бы указать в ответе). В голом Андроиде база из ассетов не копируется сама по себе и не обновляется без реализации `onUpgrade` - всё надо делать ручками.

Comment: @woesss ах точно, очки забыл надеть, извиняюсь.

Comment: Ручками в onUpgrade как я понимаю в данном случае   @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        if (oldVersion != newVersion) {
            myContext.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
            
        }
    }

Comment: @Романыч, если база используется только для чтения, то может такое и прокатит - я не проверял. Но если мы в неё пишем, то просто грохнуть и записать новую нельзя - нужно переносить данные.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел такую реализацию, работает на Android 9

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "quiz_db.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Context myContext;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        try {
            //получаем путь до БД вместе с именем.
            DB_PATH = myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).toString();
            createDataBase();
            openDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Возвращает курсор из таблицы рекордов, для того, чтобы узнать был ли рекорд в данной категории или нет.
    public Cursor getRecords(String category) {
        return database.query(
                DBContract.Entry.TABLE_RECORDS,
                null,
                DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_CATEGORY + " = ?",
                new String[] {category},
                null,
                null,
                null);
    }

    public Cursor getAllRecords() {
        return database.query(
                DBContract.Entry.TABLE_RECORDS,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null);
    }

    public void deleteRecords() {
        database.delete(DBContract.Entry.TABLE_RECORDS, null, null);
    }

    //Получаем список всех вопросов и заполняем коллекцию этими вопросами. id - это ID категории для выбора вопросов из соответствующей категории.
    public List<QuestionModel> getAllQuestions(long id) {
        List<QuestionModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
        //Открываем БД для чтения и записи
        database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //Начинаем транзакцию
        database.beginTransaction();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(
                DBContract.Entry.TABLE_QUESTIONS
                ,null
                ,DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_CATEGORYID + " = ? "
                ,new String[] {Long.toString(id)}
                ,null
                ,null
                ,null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            QuestionModel question = new QuestionModel();
            question.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Entry._ID)));
            question.setQuestion(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_QUESTION)));
            question.setAnswer(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_ANSWER)));
            question.setOpt1(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_OPT1)));
            question.setOpt2(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_OPT2)));
            question.setOpt3(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_OPT3)));
            question.setOpt4(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_OPT4)));
            list.add(question);
        }

        database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        database.endTransaction();
        cursor.close();
        database.close();
        return list;
    }

    //Возвращает список категорий викторины
    public Cursor getCategories() {
        return database.query(DBContract.Entry.TABLE_CATEGORY, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }


    /**
     * NOTE NOT USED SEE createDatabaseAlt below (it's replacment)
     * Создает пустую базу данных в системе и переписывает ее с помощью собственной базы данных.
     */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getWritableDatabase(); //<<<<<<<<<< myDatabase will be null
            database = this.getWritableDatabase();//Создает и/или открывает базу данных
        }
        if (database.isOpen()){
            database.close();
        }
        try {
            copyDataBase(); //<<<<<<<<<< Copy fails due to app_database.db (Read-only file system)Error copying database
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error(e + "Error copying database");
        }
    }

    // Alternative Create Database
    public void createDatabaseAlt() {
        if (!checkDB()) {
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error(e + "Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     *
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        String path = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        try {
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            //database does't exist yet
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null;
    }

    private boolean checkDB() {
        File db = new File(myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath());
        if (db.exists()) return true;
        File dbdir = new File(db.getParent());
        if (!dbdir.exists()) {
            dbdir.mkdirs();
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException { //Откройте локальный db в качестве входного потока
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME); //Путь к только что созданному пустому db

        //String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; //Откройте пустой бит в качестве выходного потока
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath());
        //передавать байты из входного файла в выходной файл
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        //Закрыть потоки
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    /**
     * Not used NOTE this open database as read-only and thus was the cause of one of the issues
     */
    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH;
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    /*public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }*/

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(database != null)
            database.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне не совсем понятна как работает ваша реализация . Половину методов в ней лишние и работают по принципу костылей.
В `SQLiteOpenHelper` не нашел зачем вам `DB_PATH` итд.
Ваша база создается автоматически и вычитывается из каталога assets/databases/ 
В случае когда вы базу обновили вам нужно просто стереть и перезаписать базу данных.
поднять версию на 1 с `DATABASE_VERSION = 1` до `DATABASE_VERSION = 2` это сделается автоматически в этом и суть библиотеки.
Важно что как я понимаю база будет полностью перезаписана.
Примерно такой подход должен решить вашу проблему:

```
public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
    try {
        myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        try {
            clearDB();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            setForcedUpgrade();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "MyDatabase: " + e);
    }
}



 public void clearDB() {
    if (myDataBase != null && myDataBase.isOpen()) {
        myDataBase.close();
    }
    File file = new File(context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath());
    SQLiteDatabase.deleteDatabase(file);
}
```

Работает на любой версии. На андроид 9 , возможно нужны некоторые `permissions`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
WRITE_EXTERNAL возможно тоже если EXTERNAL
```

Но это не точно может быть.
И все. Больше никакого кода с копированием вам не нужно. Дальше работаете как и работали:

```
  //  все элементы
public Cursor getAllData(String table_name) {
    myDataBase = getReadableDatabase();
    return myDataBase.query(table_name, null, null, null,
            null, null, null);
}
```

Да, писал ответ и не заметил что вы используее `SQliteOpenHelper` в моем же ответе речь идет про `SQLiteAssetsHelper`. Тем не менее рекомендую вам обратить на нее внимание. Избавляет от кучи ненужного кода.

Comment: А что за метод setForcedUpgrade();  ?

Comment: @Kolhoznik метод библиотеки, который обновляет точнее перезаписывает базу принудительно. Описано в документации

Comment: Понял, спасибо..

Answer (score 0):

В базе данных отсутствует таблица **category_tab**. Это может быть по нескольким причинам. Либо таблицы нет в той базе данных, которую вы пытаетесь скопировать, Либо вы не удачно ее копируете

Comment: по логам и так понятно что за ошибка, я не мог понять почему она возникает, но уже разобрался

Comment: Я привел пару ситуаций, при которых она может возникать. Что конкретно у вас так из кода не понять, ну по крайней мере мне